# Python indexing question within a function

Tags: python

can someone explain line by line what's going on here in this function? Particularly the indexing numbers you see next to the return and how they make sense?

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    wordlist = text.split()
    return wordlist[0][0] == wordlist[1][0]
```

Comment: It's just a list of strings. You have one list, which you access with `wordlist[index]`, and that index contains a string, which you can access individual characters in via `wordlist[index][other_index]`.

Comment: @RandomDavis nope, list a str

Comment: Is the first letter of the first word the same as the first letter of the second word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `text` is a `str`
- `wordlist` being a list of the words, as `.split()` separates on spaces
- `wordlist[0]` the first word, `wordlist[0][0]` first char of first word
- `wordlist[1]` the second word, `wordlist[1][0]` first char of second word

So you check if the first char of the 2 first words are same

```
print(animal_crackers("wa wb"))  # True
print(animal_crackers("va wb"))  # False
```

---

More details

```
animal_crackers("wabc wdef")

text=           'wabc wdef'
wordlist=       ['wabc', 'wdef']
wordlist[0]=    'wabc'       
wordlist[0][0]= 'w'       
wordlist[1]=    'wdef'       
wordlist[1][0]= 'w'
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` returns a list of strings.  For example `"I am hungry".split()` returns ["I", "am", "hunger"].

`str[index]` returns the character at that index.  So `"Foo"[0]` returns "F"

So `wordlist[0]` returns the first string in the text that was split, and so `wordlist[0][0]` returns the first character of the first word in `text`.  So `wordlist[0][0] == wordlist[1][0]` returns true if the first and second word of `text` start with the same letter.

Answer (score 0):

say, for example,

```
text = "This is my text"
```

Then `text.split()` is:

```
`['This', 'is', 'my', 'text']`
```

This list is assigned to the variable `wordlist`.

`wordlist[0]` is `This`, `wordlist[1]` is `is`, and so on.

The second index refers to the letters in each word.

so `wordlist[0][0]` is `T`, `wordlist[0][1]` is `h`, etc.

`wordlist[0][0] == wordlist[1][0]` asks if the first letter of the first word is the same as the first letter of the second word.

In the example `This is my text`, that is not the case, so the function will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordlist = text.split()
return wordlist[0][0] == wordlist[1][0]
```

First-line splits text into a list and saves its value in the variable wordlist. and the second line checks if the first letter of the first word equals the first letter in the second word. The way it work is the first index represents the word and second index represents the letter in that word. For Example

```
text = "Hello there"
wordlist = text.split()
print(wordlist[0]) #Returns "Hello"
print(wordlist[0][0]) #Returns "H"
print(wordlist[1][0]) #Returns "t"
```

and so on.

Hope my answer was helpful.